# Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, build.gradle, react-native-cli

I try to get Apk in react-native however it doesn't give me anything. release file which is in Apk file is empty and after Gradlew bundle release is finished, it says

```
    Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

I couldn't find how to solve this issue

```
    react-native run-android
info Starting JS server...
info Building and installing the app on the device (cd android && ./gradlew app:installDebug)...
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug'.
> java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/kourosh/Projects/FitnessApp/android/app/build/intermediates/transforms/dexBuilder/debug/45/androidx/versionedparcelable/R.dex

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1m 15s
19 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 18 up-to-date
error Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html
error Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

java version "12.0.1" 2019-04-16
node -v v10.16.0
npm -v 6.9.0

Comment: The same issue coming to me if you found anything to resolve it please share

Comment: The Gradle warning is not related to your app not installing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me in a React Native project. This is the step-by-step to fix it in Windows (10 64bits):

1) Run avd without Android Studio (https://windowsloop.com/launch-avd-manager-without-android-studio/)

2) In another console run in your project `gradle wrapper` (you must to have installed Gradle 5.4.1 (https://gradle.org/install/))

3) Then move to `cd android`, here run `gradlew clean`

4) Move to root `cd..` and run `react-native start`

5) In another console run in your project `react-native run-android`

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried running `./gradlew bundleRelease --warning-mode all`?

It will give you more info on what are incompatible.

Answer (score 1):

In 2020 if you have the same issue, this suggestion by the Powershell has helped me.

.\emulator.exe -avd "MyAvd"

Run the above command in the directory, where your SDK emulator is located (C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator) and then you might get some instructions as I received below:

Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:

- Start Android Studio
- Select menu "Tools > Android > SDK Manager"
- Click "SDK Tools" tab
- Check "Android Emulator" checkbox
- Click "OK"

This link would be helpful too. [link](https://windowsloop.com/launch-avd-manager-without-android-studio/)

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem you need to locate this file (gradle-wrapper.properties) The file is located in d path (android/gradle/wrapper) in your project folder....open the file and change this line

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.5-all.zip
```

to this:

```
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.0.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to project file run `gradle wrapper`.
2. Then move to cd android, here run `gradle clean`.
3. Move to root "cd.." and run `react-native start`.
4. In another console run in your project `react-native run-android`

Your project will be running!

Answer (score 0):

In my case CI/CD showed this error:

> See
> https://docs.gradle.org/7.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

I forgot to push one file to Git repository, so a project didn't assemble.